# What does Spring JMS ActiveMQ use to determine when a broker should switch Exclusive Consumers?

Tags: spring, grails, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

An exclusive consumer in Activemq is one that is sent every message from a broker until the consumer dies or goes away, at which time the broker switches consumer.

What is it that defines when the switchover takes place? How do you configure this in Spring JMS/ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Spring JMS doing the checking; it's the JMS provider, ActiveMQ.

JMS is an API specification; an empty framework, essentially. ActiveMQ provides the implementation backing for managing connections, message brokering, load-balancing, fail-over, etc.

The ActiveMQ broker handles switching-over consumers based on queue properties (you don't need to do anything special in your code):

```
queue = new ActiveMQQueue("TEST.QUEUE?consumer.exclusive=true");
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch-over takes place when either the consumer disconnects gracefully or the broker determines that the consumer has disappeared (via the `wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration` elapsing without any messages or keep-alives being received).  You don't have to configure anything if you're happy with the default value of `wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration` (30 seconds), but you can tweak that if you want to change how long it takes before the broker gives up on a client.